# Looking for a free high-quality utility that can help me create an animated GIF: a rotating picture

Tags: animated-gif

I have a `128x128` image of a cube (projection) like this one:

[image]

I need to make a rotating gif out of a static image.

I am looking for a free (or trial) utility or a script that can do that.

Os in the order of preference: Windows, Mac Leopard, Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/)

Comment: Looks good; would you be so kind to provide an animation sample which does rotation?

Comment: You'll have to handling the actual rotating yourself. Fortunately it's not very hard. http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/warping/#rotate

Answer (score 1):

[Unfreez](http://www.whitsoftdev.com/unfreez/)

> is a high-speed Windows application that will take any number of images, saved as separate GIF files, and create a single animated GIF from those images.

Comment: Thanks, I just wish there was an easy way to rotate as well.